# connection refused error when trying to install plugins

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash

i'm trying to install the `logstash-input-jmx` plugin but I keep getting a

`ERROR: Something went wrong when installing , message: Connection refused - Connection refused`

I've tried to set the proxy before running but no luck:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy.com:8099
export https_proxy=http://proxy.com:8099
./logstash-plugin install logstash-input-jmx
```

I've edited the `logstash-plugin` file to include the proxy like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset CDPATH
. "$(cd `dirname $0`/..; pwd)/bin/logstash.lib.sh"
setup

# bin/logstash-plugin is a short lived ruby script thus we can use aggressive "faster starting JRuby options"
# see https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Improving-startup-time
export JRUBY_OPTS="$JRUBY_OPTS -J-XX:+TieredCompilation -J-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -J-noverify -X-C -Xcompile.invokedynamic=false"
export http_proxy=http://proxy.com:8099
export https_proxy=http://proxy.com:8099
ruby_exec "${LOGSTASH_HOME}/lib/pluginmanager/main.rb" "$@"
```

but got the same error

I've tried to even follow this github page: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jmx

but when I get to `bin/logstash-plugin install --no-verify`...I still got the same error...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding in the proxy to `LS_JAVA_OPTS`

```
LS_JAVA_OPTS='-Dhttp.useProxy=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8099 -Dhttps.proxyHost=http://proxy.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8099' ./logstash-plugin install logstash-input-jmx
```